# How do I get the power consumption of a Supermicro server on the CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, electrical-power, supermicro, power-supply-unit

How do I get the power usage of a Supermicro server from the command line?

Comment: Although most question with this size is VLQ, imho this isn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just:

```
ipmitool dcmi power reading
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful! I assume you need to install some packages to get that to work. Do you happen to know which packages?

Comment: This can be found in the `ipmitool` package in Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the Supermicro SMCIPMITool; see the "Input Power".

```
[root@mgmt ~/SMCIPMITool/SMCIPMITool_2.11.0_bundleJRE_Linux_x64_20140704]# ./SMCIPMITool supermicro-ipmi-interface ADMIN password pminfo
strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file
 [SlaveAddress = 78h] [Module 1]
 Item                           |                Value 
 ----                           |                ----- 
 Status                         |     [STATUS OK](00h) 
 Input Voltage                  |             225.75 V 
 Input Current                  |               1.12 A 
 Main Output Voltage            |               12.1 V 
 Main Output Current            |              17.71 A 
 Temperature 1                  |              36C/97F 
 Temperature 2                  |             47C/117F 
 Fan 1                          |             1408 RPM 
 Fan 2                          |             1056 RPM 
 Main Output Power              |                214 W 
 Input Power                    |                244 W 
 PMBus Revision                 |               0x1B12 
 PWS Serial Number              |      P1K28CD34ZB0791 
 PWS Module Number              |         PWS-1K28P-SQ 
 PWS Revision                   |               REV1.1 

 [SlaveAddress = 7Ah] [Module 2]
 Item                           |                Value 
 ----                           |                ----- 
 Status                         |     [STATUS OK](00h) 
 Input Voltage                  |              227.5 V 
 Input Current                  |                1.0 A 
 Main Output Voltage            |              12.13 V 
 Main Output Current            |              16.43 A 
 Temperature 1                  |              34C/93F 
 Temperature 2                  |             45C/113F 
 Fan 1                          |             1376 RPM 
 Fan 2                          |             1056 RPM 
 Main Output Power              |                198 W 
 Input Power                    |                218 W 
 PMBus Revision                 |               0x1D12 
 PWS Serial Number              |      P1K28CD30YB1369 
 PWS Module Number              |         PWS-1K28P-SQ 
 PWS Revision                   |               REV1.1
```

The tool can be found here: ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/utility/SMCIPMItool/

[edit]

If you get a "Can't login to [ip-address]" while the password is correct, try this:
IPMI web interface -> Miscellaneous -> SMC RAKP -> Disable

Comment: That doesn't quite give you the power usage, you need to do this:

./SMCIPMITool  IP_ADDR ADMIN password  dcmi powerStatus

Instantaneous power reading    | 237W                          
Minimum during sampling period | 10W                           
Maximum during sampling period | 509W                          
Average during sampling period | 300W                          
IPMI timestamp                 | 2019/11/26 19:03:01           
Sampling period                | 1477117856 Milliseconds
Power reading state            | Activated

Answer (score 1):

for FreeBSD:

```
pkg install ipmitool
kldload ipmi
```